# EJBCA OCSP service Default URI ,how to set defult value

Tags: ocsp

When building the ejbca certificate service,
how should this value be set?
Do I need to replace `my.pki` with the domain name of ejbca?

*OCSP service Default URI
Default CRL Distribution Point
CA issuer Default URI*

Consultation post, not sure what its role is.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set this value to anything, never.
If you are using OCSP (RFC6960), and including the OCSP URL in the AIA extension in the certificate, and have many CAs and many certificate profiles. Then this setting can help easy your number of different configurations.